How to evaluate performance of classification model for different subsets of classes?
Consider a classification problem where there are N classes. While this may seem strange, I have a model that processes features, and essentially, evaluate which classes are impossible (or near impossible) to classify correctly based on the features. Therefore, we can exclude these classes when making predictions because we already know we fail in such cases (in other words quantify when model is useless).
I want to evaluate how well this, but simply evaluating accuracy isn't a fair comparison. Consider I am unable to classify all but 2, then I could compare the accuracy for the classes I "can classify" and "cannot classify". However, I will have 50% for the classes I "can classify" by just randomly guessing in this case. Maybe, it appears as a good improvement, but a random guesser has high accruacy relative to the number of classes.
What metrics can be used to evaluate such cases? There must be a metric for this kind of scenario.

Classification is not usually a good goal.  See this.

For classifiable classes, after excluding unclassifiable samples you can still use the usual proper cross entropy loss/Brier score, accuracy, precision, recall, F1 score/AUC-ROC, or some proprietary misclassification-cost adjusted metric, etc.
To further address your rightly concerned issues such as using conditional accuracy metric in the case of only 2 classifiable classes, metrics like Expected Calibration Error (ECE) can provide a clearer view of how well the model's classification confidence corresponds to the actual test outcomes, which can be particularly informative and reliable when dealing with a limited number of classes.

A classifier might separate the classes well, but be poorly calibrated, meaning that the estimated class probabilities are far from the true class probabilities. In this case, a calibration step may help improve the estimated probabilities. A variety of metrics exist that are aimed to measure the extent to which a classifier produces well-calibrated probabilities. Foundational work includes the Expected Calibration Error (ECE).

By ECE one can see how well the model's predicted probabilities for the classes it can classify correspond to the true outcomes without the noise introduced by unconfident unclassifiable classes, thus such focused evaluation helps in deciding whether the model's predictions are trustworthy enough for critical applications. In your specific 50% random model hypothetical case, ECE can help identify the most likely noncalibrated performance, unless your test data is also 50% balanced which is very rare and you still have all the above other metrics to evaluate further.
Finally you should have a coverage rate metric to measure how many instances are classified as classifiable versus unclassifiable which helps to understand the model's applicability.
